# Returning from a for loop which has an async call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function which is getting called once:

```
exports.validate = function(roomData, callback) {
  console.log('This only prints only once!');

  getAllRooms(function(rooms) {
    if (rooms.length === 0) {
      callback(true);
      return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
      let key = "roomAdmin:" + rooms[i].roomName;

      redis.hgetall(key, function() {
        let newUrl = roomData.url.toLowerCase();
        let existingUrl = rooms[i].url.toLowerCase();
        let newRoomName = roomData.roomName.toLowerCase();
        let existingRoomName = rooms[i].roomName.toLowerCase();

        if (newUrl === existingUrl || newRoomName === existingRoomName) {
          console.log('This prints');
          callback(false);
          return;
        }
        if (i === rooms.length - 1) {
          console.log('But this prints also?');
          callback(true);
          return;
        }
      })
    }
  });
};
```

I am trying to loop through a set of redis objects and compare some fields to some give new data. If there is a match I want to callback with a false and return. If there is no match I want to return true.

I can see my logic is wrong below as hgetall is async so both returns get called, so how do I stop execution and return as soon as I find a match?

Thanks

Comment: your logic is not totally wrong, you have a callback as parameter, so the code will go on correctly when result is there. However, there is no need to return at all, this is not that which will trigger the execution of the code that has to be done after. All that's to be done after must be in the callback, not sequentially placed after the `validate` call. A simple solution would be to wrap `redis.hgetall` call in a function that will take as additional arguments `i` and `callback` to store as a var. Like this, the value of `i` will be right

Answer (score 1):

Stopping execution is on responsibility of `hgetall` function, so you can use simplest straightforward solution - pass to it array function, which calls your local let-assigned function. After match is found (Or error occurred), just replace local function to empty. Modern ES interpreter optimizers would execute code fast enough, but additional callbacks will not performed.

Something like following:

```
let cbc = function() {
    let newUrl = roomData.url.toLowerCase();
    let existingUrl = rooms[i].url.toLowerCase();
    let newRoomName = roomData.roomName.toLowerCase();
    let existingRoomName = rooms[i].roomName.toLowerCase();
    // ......
    if(found) {
        cbc = () => {};
        callback(result);
        return
    }
}    
// ......
redis.hgetall(key, (...args) => cbc(...args));
```

Comment: something makes a bell ring in my brain here.. how is the callback called when nothing is found and no error occur? And maybe i am wrong, but doesn't this code rely on synchronous-like execution? if first instance takes more time to answer than the second one (and throws error), won't `cbc` function still exist for the second instance?

Comment: @Kaddath You are right, it's just code concept for suggested use case. Of course, original `cbc` function should monitor n-th count of invocation, and perform false-branch callback at last iteration. About async execution, most likely, it's not problem, because every closure has it's own instance. And again - it mostly answer to question 'How to return from async callback', so achieve stop calling callback of not-controllable function.